# options aren't showing in my select tag | Angular and Ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to display my options (category.name for category in categories):

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;padding:0;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">
<div class="col col-white" style="height:45px;background-color:#EDEEF1;padding-top:6px">
    <div class="list" style="max-width:80%;margin-left:10%">
        <label class="item item-input item-select" style="border:none;padding:0;border-radius:25px;color:black">
            <div class="input-label" style="color:grey; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;z-index:9999">
                {{selectedCategory.name.name ? selectedCategory.name.name : 'Välj kategori'}}
            </div>
            <select ng-click="test()" id="helloo" ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
                <option selected value="">Välj kategori</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason they wont show. I've asked around and some people say it has to do with some innerHTML, others say it's my CSS who's causing this. It feels like there's no solution to this bug whatsoever!!

However, when I inspect the elements I can see all my option tags with Chrome Developing tools, but not in my browser.

I really appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Please add controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `category.name.name` instead of `category.name`

```
<select ng-change="test()" ng-model="selectedCategory" 
 ng-options="category.name.name for category in categories">
   <option selected value="">Välj kategori</option>
</select>
```